# Having issues with my Socket.io chat

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, chat

Im having issues on building a chat with node.js and socket.io . Till now i successfully achieved on building a chat with whisper function, which showes the users aswell. 
Now the following things that i still need are:

1. Adding rooms, joining rooms and deletes rooms.
2. PM(Personal Messaging) a user ( It's not the same as Whispering)
3. Create Groups of people who can interact with each other.
4. Status message. ( Is he Online, Idle or Offline)

Advanced Features.

1. Collaboration ( What exactly the user is doing)
2. Possibility of making a chat responsive for Handheld Purpose.
3. Login function

These features are mostly what keeps me on bay with this chat. Im stuck at the moment with the Rooms part.Other than that i already could list them. But sadly not join them.

Here you have the code:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d0b52dd582b07ab8318d

I would be happy if someone could help me or atleast give me a hint where to look

I thank you for the Feedback and wish you a great day :)

[EDIT]

Updated Code : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7b508621d2c4b70be1ec

Answer (score 0):

For rooms, make use of socket.io. they provide room functionality. You can broadcast in the room. Join the room. No need to exit the room explicitely as it is done on socket disconnection [check here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms)

Comment: Joining the room will be done like this - `socket.join("Room Name")`. This should be inside `connection` event's callback. :) like this - `io.on('connection',function(socket){});`

Comment: Thats weird. Because i am using the socket.io part of joining a room and subscribing. You can check on the link if your unsure. I just can't seem to be able to switch rooms.

Comment: okay, did you successfully leave the room ? can you try printing the room members in switch function, so that we can get some idea about leaving was successful or not. Also try printing room members on joining new room.

Comment: Yes. Im even further than that. I can now even create rooms and communicate with others in the same room. Just i can't seem to update the users specific when im in a room.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7b508621d2c4b70be1ec

Comment: @slyPEDRO : what are you getting in `updateUser()` in `usersOutput` variable ? are all users listed ?